# How Link to Route in JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, hyperlink, date-format

I'm using Laravel 8.

I wish I could link the field "nama" to show the categories in detail (the examples in red arrows).

[image]

**JS for table**

```html
@push('scripts')
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#kategoris-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'kategori/json',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'nama', name: 'nama' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
@endpush
```

I also wish to know how to set the date format because when I looked at that field it feels so messed up. Here's my view table.

[image]

Comment: you can use `render()` in datatable https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#kategoris-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'kategori/json',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'nama', name: 'nama',
                fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html("<a href='/category_details/"+oData.id+"'>"+oData.nama+"</a>");
                }
            },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
```

You can read here more about it - https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell